# Bundler.require(*Rails.groups) Causes ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block After Ruby/Rails Upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an older Heroku application that requires an update from a fairly old version to the newest.

However, after upgrading Ruby from 2.7.2 to 3.1.2 and Rails from 5.2.3 to 7.0.6 using bundler 2.4.15 when running rails zeitwerk:check or Heroku local the code fails on the application.rb on Bundler.require(*Rails.groups) with ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block

I've tried moving the code into the block and updating/fixing ruby/rails versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an old gem version, written for pre Ruby 2.7, that uses the bare `proc` syntax. Upgrade your other gems too.